# How does 32-bit MASM mode differ from 64-bit?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, 32bit-64bit, masm

To write a complete program in 32-bit assembly language using MASM one may start like this,

```
.686
.model flat,c
.stack 100h
.data
number sdword 5
.code
main proc
mov eax,number
ret
main endp
end main
```

whereas in 64-bit mode the code is written as

```
.data
number sdword 5
.code
main proc
mov eax,number
ret
main endp
end
```

The settings are set to default which led to occur an error while assembling in a 64-bit mode not because the platform is set to Win32, but instead the default entry point mainCRTStartup. To fix the problem it must be set to `main` in Advanced Linker options.

My question is, why encountering such a problem not happening in 32-bit mode, and what does the mainCRTStartup entry point referring to anyway? My second question is, why assembling in the 64-bit mode we omit the first directive lines `.686 .model flat,c .stack 100h` don't we have to allocate the stack, as well as the language type?
The directive  [`.686`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-686?view=msvc-160) indicates to,

> Enables assembly of nonprivileged instructions for the Pentium Pro processor. (32-bit MASM only.)

why it's not the case in the 64-bit mode?

Answer (score 5):

32-bit MASM had a choice between 16-bit and 32-bit executables, depending on the directives.  This is not the case when building 64-bit code, so fewer directives are relevant.

The x86-64 ISA guarantees that PPro instructions are supported so there's no need to enable them.  (Same for SSE / SSE2).  The fact that your code is running in 64-bit mode means they're available, just like 386 features like `movzx` in `.model flat`.  **But you choose that with command-line options, not directives,** in MASM.

Does MASM not have directives for other later extensions like `.haswell` or `.bmi2` to help you avoid using newer instructions by accident, like AVX2 `vpermpd ymm0, ymm1, 0x01` when you only meant to use AVX1?  Some other assemblers do have features like that, such as YASM's `CPU` directive, or the GNU assembler can let you restrict features.  (By default GAS and YASM/NASM accept everything they knows about.)

---

**x86-64 long mode also forces a flat memory model** (CS.base = DS.base = ES.base = SS.base) so there's no need to choose a memory model.  Non-flat memory segmentation is only possible under a 64-bit kernel in compat mode (like the user-space side of 32-bit or 16-bit protected mode).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes

Also, MASM `.model` was also a proxy for assuming 32-bit mode vs. 16-bit mode, which was weird.  Other assemblers separate this more orthogonally, like `bits 16` / `bits 32` / `bits 64` to set the current mode.  (But in NASM that doesn't change the output file format; that just lets you put 64-bit code into a 32-bit object file which you don't want to do unless you're writing a kernel that *switches* modes.)

---

For `.stack`, the max size of the main-thread stack is set by the linker (with the `/STACK` command-line option), not the assembler.  That replaces the mechanism of having the assembler put metadata in the `.obj` file for the linker to find, or however it actually worked.  (AFAIK `.stack` only ever mattered for 16-bit executables anyway, not even for `.model flat`.
You wouldn't usually want a tiny 256-byte stack in 32-bit code).

Comment: *Does MASM not have directives* - The [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/directives-reference?view=msvc-160) of directives for VS2019's masm says "no."  They do have processor directives, but they are all marked as "32 bit only."

Comment: Stating x86-64 long mode forces a flat memory model, does it force also not to have any high-level directives such as, `.if .else .repeat` etc.?

Comment: That is to say, in the x86-64 mode assembly is written purely with unprivileged instructions to address directly the processor instead of the assembler then the processor as it could be the case in 32-bit mode?

Comment: @PeterCordes Excuse my ignorance about assembly language, I'm just a beginner. I don't see in the 64-bit mode language type used for callings such as C?

Comment: @EnthusiastiC: I don't understand your question at all.  What does "language type" mean?  64-bit code uses a different calling convention than 32-bit mode, somewhat like 32-bit fastcall, but you don't need any special help from the assembler.  You just reserve shadow space, put args in registers (and the stack if more than 4), and do `call symbol_name`.

Comment: @EnthusiastiC x64 MASM doesn't support any of the "higher level" directives like `.if`, `.while` and `INVOKE`. They would've needed to be updated to generate appropriate 64-bit instructions and Microsoft never bothered. Like Peter Cordes said, high level directives like those defeat the whole purpose of writing assembly code. If you want a high level programming language then you should be using a high level programming language. A C compiler, for example, will generate much better code for it's function calls and `if` and `while` statements than MASM did for  `INVOKE` `.if` and `.while`.

Comment: @RossRidge That's what I want to hear about. But what does it mean they would have needed to be updated to generate appropriate 64-bit instructions? How to INVOKE printf and scanf functions in 64-bit?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, @RossRidge.  Removed my earlier comment you were referring to where I incorrectly assumed that `.if` would still work in 64-bit mode.  (Where I said that those high-level directives were not something you'd ever want to use anyway, because one of the few reasons for writing asm by hand these days is performance.  I'd always want to see the actual instructions when tuning code, so I can spot redundancy and maybe think of better ways to implement a loop condition or a branch based on stuff I have in registers.)

Comment: @EnthusiastiC: You don't use INVOKE.  Just follow the calling convention and call them with a `call` instruction.  If you want an example, google `x64 masm printf` or something, or search on stack overflow.

Comment: @EnthusiastiC  That's a separate question, one that's already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390886/calling-c-function-from-masm-64

Comment: So, in summary, Microsoft didn't update 32-bit high-level directives to be able to implement them in the newer 64-bit version because they are meaningless since assembly would've been a waste. Additionally, the 64-bit version is different from the 32-bit to a point that it could not specify the language type as used to be the case in 32-bit in `.model flat, c`.

Comment: @EnthusiastiC: Yup, that about covers it.  MASM's high-level stuff dates back to a time when whole programs for DOS were often written by hand in asm, whether the people working on them wanted to be writing in asm or not, and performance didn't really matter for some parts of it.