# anyone know what import kernel,\ GetModuleHandle,'GetModuleHandleA',\ExitProcess,'ExitProcess' for in FASMW ??? PLS Hyelp

Tags: fasm

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

```
    library kernel,'KERNEL32.DLL',\
            user,'USER32.DLL'

    import  kernel,\
            GetModuleHandle,'GetModuleHandleA',\
            ExitProcess,'ExitProcess'

    import  user,\
            DialogBoxParam,'DialogBoxParamA',\
            EndDialog,'EndDialog',\
            SetDlgItemText,'SetDlgItemTextA',\
            GetDlgItemText,'GetDlgItemTextA',\
            SetDlgItemInt,'SetDlgItemInt',\
            GetDlgItemInt,'GetDlgItemInt',\
            GetDlgItem,'GetDlgItem',\
            SetFocus,'SetFocus',\
            GetWindowLong,'GetWindowLongA',\
            SetWindowLong,'SetWindowLongA',\
            CallWindowProc,'CallWindowProcA',\
            SendMessage,'SendMessageA',\
            TrackPopupMenu,'TrackPopupMenu',\
            LoadMenu,'LoadMenuA',\
            GetSubMenu,'GetSubMenu',\
            CheckMenuItem,'CheckMenuItem'
```

Anyone know what Kernel32.dll for in this code ?? PLS

Answer (score 0):

`.idata` is the import data section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-idata-section. It specifies the functions from dynamic libraries (DLLs) that your program uses.

With FASM, you specify entries in this section with the `import` and `library` macros. First you define the DLLs you want to use with `library`, listing the name you give it and the name of the DLL for each library you want to use.
Next, you specify which functions you want to use from these libraries with `import`, specifying first the library name you gave it with the `library` macro, and then the name you will reference the function by in your code and the name of the function as exported in the DLL, for each function you want to use. See https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32#1.2.

For example, your snippet imports the `GetModuleHandleA` function as `GetModuleHandle` from `KERNEL32.DLL`, such that you can write `invoke GetModuleHandle, someModuleName` in your code. Documentation on this function can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlea, which lists the DLL which contains the function at the bottom of the page.

If you think specifying all this is a bit verbose, you can use the definitions from FASM itself:

```
library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL',\
        user32,'USER32.DLL'

include 'api/kernel32.inc'
include 'api/user32.inc'
```

Or don't define the `.idata` yourself but use the poorly-named [`.end` macro](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32#2.2) at the end of your code, which does this automatically:

```
.end yourMainFunctionLabelNameHere
```

This does require you to `include 'win<1><2>x.inc`, where `<1>` is `32` or `64` depending on the processor architecture and `<2>` is `a` or `w` depending on if you want to use ANSI or Wide char (UTF-16) functions (e.g. should it define `DialogBoxParam,'DialogBoxParamA'` or `DialogBoxParam,'DialogBoxParamW'`). See the code snippet in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65340051/4454665) for an example of what I mean.